# How to append columns, grouped and without duplicates?

Tags: sql, append, substring, concatenation, multiple-columns

I currently have a data set with each row supposed to represent the Hazardous Code of an item. Some items have the same Hazardous Code multiple times as it represents different descriptions for the goods inside.

My aim is to convert the below data set to have every distinct `gkey` but with all its respective and distinct `imdg_class` values in that `gkey`'s row:

Current result of data:

[image: Current result of data]

So in the case of `gkey` = `4524111`, I would expect `imdg_class` to have `3, 8`.

Note: the `imdg_class` column has the following distinct list of values

`1.1B`
`1.1C`
`1.1D`
`1.2C`
`1.2E`
`1.2G`
`1.3C`
`1.3G`
`1.4B`
`1.4C`
`1.4G`
`1.4S`
`1.5D`
`2.1` 
`2.2` 
`2.3` 
`3`   
`4.1` 
`4.2` 
`4.3` 
`5.1` 
`5.2` 
`6.1` 
`6.2` 
`7`   
`8`   
`9`

I would appreciate the help anyone can provide.

EDIT: 
My versions are as follows: 
`Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                     14.0.17213.0`
`Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                       14.0.1016.232` 
`Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                        10.0.16299.15` 
`Microsoft MSXML                        3.0 4.0 6.0` 
`Microsoft Internet Explorer                        9.11.16299.0` 
`Microsoft .NET Framework                       4.0.30319.42000` 
`Operating System                       6.3.16299`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, databases support some sort of string aggregation function.  For instance, it is called `group_concat()` in MySQL and you can just do:

```
select gkey,
       group_concat(distinct imdg_class)
from t
group by gkey;
```

In Postgres, the function is `string_agg()`.  Same in SQL Server.  In Oracle, it is called `listagg()` -- but unfortunately doesn't remove duplicates so a subquery is needed.

`string_agg()` in SQL Server is available in SQL Server 2017+.  Before then, you can use the XML version:

```
select gkey,
       stuff( (select distinct ',' + imdg_class
               from t t2
               where t2.gkey = t.gkey
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            )
from (select distinct gkey from t) t;
```

Comment: So I get the following: 
`'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name`

Inspecting my system are my version:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17213.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.232
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.16299.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.16299